# skimage How to get correct color when converting RGB to HSV. Understanding Hue

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, rgb, scikit-image

I tried to convert an RGB to HSV using skimage and getting behavior that I do not expect. Here is some sample code that I would expect to produce only blue. This is important as (later on) as I would like to take real images and determine how much of each color is present across the whole image by referring to the hue.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage as ski
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define my own color in RGB, should be B
tested = np.ones(shape=(100,100,3))*200
tested[:,:,0] =0
tested[:,:,1] =0

hsv_test_img_arr=ski.color.rgb2hsv(tested)

hue_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 0]
sat_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 1]
value_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 2]

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(8, 2))

ax1.imshow(hue_img, cmap='hsv')
ax1.set_title('hue channel')
ax1.axis('off')

ax2.imshow(value_img)
ax2.set_title('value channel')
ax2.axis('off')

ax3.imshow(sat_img)
ax3.set_title('sat channel')
ax3.axis('off')
```

[image: output]

Comment: Try using a grey colormap and also printing the `[0,0]` value of your hue_img, sat_img and value_img.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to normalize the data correctly. Values in all channels range between 0 and 1. So you need to give this information to `imshow`,

```
imshow(..., vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage as ski
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define my own color in RGB, should be B
tested = np.ones(shape=(100,100,3))*200
tested[:,:,0] =0
tested[:,:,1] =0

hsv_test_img_arr=ski.color.rgb2hsv(tested)

hue_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 0]
sat_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 1]
value_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 2]

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(8, 2))

im1 = ax1.imshow(hue_img, cmap='hsv', vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax1.set_title('hue channel')
ax1.axis('off')
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)

im2 = ax2.imshow(value_img, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax2.set_title('value channel')
ax2.axis('off')
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)

im3 = ax3.imshow(sat_img, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax3.set_title('sat channel')
ax3.axis('off')
fig.colorbar(im3, ax=ax3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Taking a real image makes this more useful though.

```
import skimage as ski
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/World%2C_administrative_divisions_-_de_-_colored_%28all_countries%29.svg/640px-World%2C_administrative_divisions_-_de_-_colored_%28all_countries%29.svg.png"
tested = plt.imread(img)[:,:,:3]

hsv_test_img_arr=ski.color.rgb2hsv(tested)

hue_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 0]
sat_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 1]
value_img = hsv_test_img_arr[:, :, 2]

fig, ((ax0, ax1), (ax2, ax3)) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(8, 6))

im0 = ax0.imshow(tested)
ax0.set_title('original')
ax0.axis('off')

im1 = ax1.imshow(hue_img, cmap='hsv', vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax1.set_title('hue channel')
ax1.axis('off')
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)

im2 = ax2.imshow(value_img, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax2.set_title('value channel')
ax2.axis('off')
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)

im3 = ax3.imshow(sat_img, cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax3.set_title('sat channel')
ax3.axis('off')
fig.colorbar(im3, ax=ax3)

plt.show()
```

[image]